# Displaying Class contents on form

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a working list being populated by a class (or so I assume) and am attempting to display the only record in a set of Textboxes on a form.

```
public partial class frm_people : Form
{

    public frm_people()
    {
        // Loads the Form
        InitializeComponent();

        LoadData();

        ShowData();

    }

    // Global Variables

    private People peopleClass;
    private ArrayList peopleArrayList;

    private int numberOfPeople;
    private int currentPeopleShown;

    private void ShowData()
    {
        // Add to Text Box based on current Record
        txt_peopleName.Text = ((People)peopleArrayList[currentPeopleshown]).name;**
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {

        List<People> peopleList = new List<People>();

        People data = new People("James Bond", false, "Cardiff");

        peopleList.Add(data);

        numberOfPeople = 1;
        currentPeopleShown = 0;
    }
}
```

I get an error (noted by **):

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I'm aware that classes are worked with by reference, how would one attempt this way of displaying records? The end aim is to be able to scroll between multiple records freely, by using the `currentPeopleShown` variable.

Comment: I don't see where peopleArrayList is being set.  If it's never set then the value is null and that is why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could eliminate the ArrayList all together and just do this

```
public partial class frm_people : Form
{
   List<People> peopleList;
    public frm_people()
    {
        // Loads the Form
        InitializeComponent();

        peopleList = new List<People>();
        LoadData();

        ShowData();

    }

    // Global Variables

    private People peopleClass;

    private int numberOfPeople;
    private int currentPeopleShown;

    private void ShowData()
    {
        // Add to Text Box based on current Record
        txt_peopleName.Text = (peopleList[0]).name;**
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {

        People data = new People("James Bond", false, "Cardiff");

        peopleList.Add(data);

        numberOfPeople = 1;
        currentPeopleShown = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the error states "peopleList does not exist in current context"  The whole things works when I move the LoadData method into the ShowData one.  I think I may have a problem with the Class itself, i'll look into it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private void ShowData()
    {
        // Add to Text Box based on current Record
      if(peopleArrayList[currentPeopleshown]!=null)
        txt_peopleName.Text = ((People)peopleArrayList[currentPeopleshown]).name;
    }
```

Comment: The same errors will present itself on the end of the if line.

Answer (score 0):

Your peopleList is out of scope.

```
List<People> peopleList = new List<People>();

private void LoadData()
{
  //...
}
```

The array isn't being used, so use the peopleList:

```
txt_peopleName.Text = peopleList[currentPeopleshown].name;
```

You won't need the `numberOfPeople` variable, you can just use `peopleList.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting peopleArrayList?

Try something on these lines:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    peopleArrayList = new ArrayList();
    People data = new People("James Bond", false, "Cardiff");

    peopleArrayList.Add(data);

    numberOfPeople = 1;
    currentPeopleShown = 0;
}
```